# attack bitcoin through writing data directly into output's scriptPubKeys

Tags: attack

In this [post](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/50819/colored-coin-adds-meta-data-to-op-return-why-isnt-this-frowned-upon), [Steve Ellis](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/18506/steve-ellis) wrote :

> "[...]Writing data directly into a output's scriptPubKey is not prunable[...]where as non-prunable outputs will forever create bloat and slowdown the set traversal(e.g. during block verification).[...]

Wouldn't this be a relatively cost effective way to slow down bitcoin by writing the maximum possible data into into scriptPubKey?

Answer (score 1):

No. This is very fast way to spend your money for nothing. You can not put arbitrary data into to `scriptPubKey` because there is limited number of `standard scripts`.

The best thing you can do nowadays is sending 550 satoshi (0.00000550 btc) for bare-multisig outputs m-of-3 created from uncompressed public keys. This will enlarge the UTxO database ( look at https://statoshi.info/dashboard/db/unspent-transaction-output-set ) but will not slow down network itself